# single finger rotation gesture with swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I'd like to know how I could be able to recognise a single finger rotation gesture (when someone draws a circle on the screen).

I've seen [this class](https://github.com/MichMich/XMCircleGestureRecognizer) that works perfectly and that's exactly what I'd like to do (a dimmer or something like that) but I can't use it in my app as it gets above the other gesture and I'm not able to recognize them anymore (I never left the touchesEnded of the class and go back to my class).

So I was wondering if you could bring me some help to recognise that gesture (the last of my app...)

I'm already able to recognise tap, swipes, pinches, long press, and that's the only one I miss.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.timer.invalidate()
    isPinched = false
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    startTime = getCurrentMillis()

    for touch in touches{
        let point = touch.location(in: self.view)
        for (index,finger)  in fingers.enumerated() {
            if finger == nil {
                fingers[index] = String(format: "%p", touch)

                if (finger1.isEmpty){
                    finger1 = [point.x, point.y]
                } else if (finger2.isEmpty){
                    finger2 = [point.x, point.y]
                } else if (finger3.isEmpty){
                    finger3 = [point.x, point.y]
                } else if (finger4.isEmpty){
                    finger4 = [point.x, point.y]
                } else if (finger5.isEmpty){
                    finger5 = [point.x, point.y]
                } else if (finger6.isEmpty){
                    finger6 = [point.x, point.y]
                } else if (finger7.isEmpty){
                    finger7 = [point.x, point.y]
                } else if (finger8.isEmpty){
                    finger8 = [point.x, point.y]
                } else if (finger9.isEmpty){
                    finger9 = [point.x, point.y]
                } else if (finger10.isEmpty){
                    finger10 = [point.x, point.y]
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }

    //Where I call the function when the touch is long enough, I recognize longPress and rotation in it

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.35, target: self, selector: #selector(increaseValue), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    if ascending {
        ascending = false
    }
    else {
        ascending = true
    }
}

// Keep track of each finger and register the position

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

    for touch in touches {
        let point = touch.location(in: self.view)
        for (index,finger) in fingers.enumerated() {
            if let finger = finger, finger == String(format: "%p", touch) {
                switch (index){
                case 0 :
                    finger1 += [point.x, point.y]
                case 1 :
                    finger2 += [point.x, point.y]
                case 2 :
                    finger3 += [point.x, point.y]
                case 3 :
                    finger4 += [point.x, point.y]
                case 4 :
                    finger5 += [point.x, point.y]
                case 6 :
                    finger6 += [point.x, point.y]
                case 7 :
                    finger7 += [point.x, point.y]
                case 8 :
                    finger8 += [point.x, point.y]
                case 9 :
                    finger9 += [point.x, point.y]
                case 10 :
                    finger10 += [point.x, point.y]
                default :
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    endTime = getCurrentMillis()

    for touch in touches {
        for (index,finger) in fingers.enumerated() {
            if let finger = finger, finger == String(format: "%p", touch) {
                fingers[index] = nil
                break
            }
        }
    }

    direction[0] = ""
    direction[1] = ""
    direction[2] = ""
    direction[3] = ""
    direction[4] = ""

    if finger1.count != 0 {
        direction[0] = GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger1, index: 0)
    }
    if finger2.count != 0 {
        direction[1] = GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger2, index: 1)
    }
    if finger3.count != 0 {
        direction[2] = GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger3, index: 2)
    }
    if finger4.count != 0 {
        direction[3] = GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger4, index: 3)
    }
    if finger5.count != 0 {
        direction[4] = GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger5, index: 4)
    }

    if Int64(endTime - startTime) < 400 {
// Recognize Swipe, tap, double tap, etc
    }

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
        self.directionLabel.text = self.labelUptade
        self.finger1 = []
        self.finger2 = []
        self.finger3 = []
        self.finger4 = []
        self.finger5 = []
        self.finger6 = []
        self.finger7 = []
        self.finger8 = []
        self.finger9 = []
        self.finger10 = []
    }
}

func increaseValue() -> Int {

    labelUptade = String(value)

    if (Conditions){
        //Recognition of long press
    } 
    else if !finger1.isEmpty {

        let a: CGFloat = finger1[0] - CGPoint.zero.x
        let b: CGFloat = finger1[1] - CGPoint.zero.y
        let c: CGFloat = finger1[finger1.count - 2] - CGPoint.zero.x
        let d: CGFloat = finger1[finger1.count - 1] - CGPoint.zero.y

        let atanA: CGFloat = atan2(a, b)
        let atanB: CGFloat = atan2(c, d)

        // convert radiants to degrees
        angle = (Float(atanA - atanB) * 360 / Float.pi) + 180
        print("angle = \(angle)")

        angle1 += angle
        print("angle1 = \(angle1)")
    }
    return value
}
```

This is what I've done so far. As you can see I'm calling the function each 0.350s, can it be a problem? I'd be glad to hear any recommendations.

Thanks for your help.